# MySQL UPDATE if exist, INSERT if not into multiple tables

Tags: mysql

There's two related tables. **t_goods**(id, name, descriprion) and **t_prices**(goods_id, price). I need to set/update the field 'description' from **t_goods** and the field 'price' from **t_prices**.
Here's my solution:

```
UPDATE `t_goods`
LEFT JOIN 
    `t_prices`
    ON t_prices.product_id = t_goods.id 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 'bla-bla-bla' AS description, '123456' AS id, 1000 AS price) AS DataToUpdateTable
    ON DataToUpdateTable.id= t_goods.id
SET t_prices.price = DataToUpdateTable.price,
    t_goods.description = DataToUpdateTable.description
```

That works fine, but there's a problem: if no price is set before (t_prices.price is NULL in the above query) it remains unset.
I need to INSERT instead of UPDATE in that case. And MySQL offers a solution (INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement). But it's impossible to INSERT into multiple tables.
How can I workaround that problem?
I kindly ask for your advice

Comment: I don't think there's a SQL-only solution for this. You'll need to do it as separate `SELECT` and `UPDATE` or `INSERT` queries using the client programming language or a stored procedure.

Comment: You could do this with some dark magic and the help of some triggers, but is that really a good idea?

Comment: How many rows are there likely to be?  There's a case to be made to not store null for prices because they are often used for aggregation.

Comment: I would do this as two `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statements together in a transaction. I can't think of another good solution either. Not every task needs to be done in a single SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I did as @Bill suggested — two queries inside a transaction and a temporary table for efficiency